# Glassdoor API not working with $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api

I'm having an issue with my AngularJS call to Glassdoor API. It keeps giving me No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
$http.get('https://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=P_KEY&t.k=KEY&userip=0.0.0.0&useragent=&format=json&v=1&action=employers&q=ibm').then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.data);
    $scope.employers = resp.data;
}, function(error, resp) {
    console.log(error, resp);
});
```

It does work if I click the link specifically but the angular call doesn't.

Server.js to deal with CORS.

```
var express = require('express');
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 //var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
 var app = express();
 var cors = require('cors');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var data = '';


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
port: '3306',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'jobs'
});

//app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:YOUR_PORT'}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
 });

 app.use(serveStatic(require("path").join(__dirname, "/views"))); // Serves everything in the views directory
 // Example: url.com/css/style.css serves views/css/style.css

  app.get('/api/jobs', function(req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY company ASC', function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
      console.log('There was a problem reading from jobs database :' + err.stack);
      res.sendStatus(500).send('There was a problem reading from jobs database');
      return;
  }

  console.log('results:', results);
  res.send(results);
 });
});

app.post('/api/jobs_post', function(req, res, next){

});

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {console.log("Running")});

var gracefulShutdown = function() {
console.log('Shutting down');
server.close(function() {
    console.log('Closed out remaining connections');
});
connection.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error closing the connection to jobs database: ' + err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection terminated successfully!')
    }
});
}
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown); // Server is killed
process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown); // Ctrl-C is pressed in the terminal
```

This is my fun personal project: https://csjobsco-gchavez1011.c9users.io:8081/index.html

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Would it be from my server? I have already 'dealt' with the cors issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the Glassdoor API directly from the browser, hence the "not allowed" cross origin error.
You'll have to do the call from a server, or through a proxy (I guess that's what the server.js is for).

Comment: You're correct in it having to be a server call I'm having an issue though of were only on request is allowed.